# How can I send a message box if text hasn't been saved within X mins and the user wants to close the app?

Tags: c#

Here's the pseudo code:

```
  private void ForgetSave()
{    
   if (the SaveRegularly method hasn't been used within 3 mins)

      MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save any changes before closing?")

  ......... the code continues.
}  
   else
{  
    this.close();
}
```

Does anybody know how to write the first line of the if statement?

Comment: use a timer and set a variable indicating if the timer has elapsed to indicate the time of inactivity then check that in your if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ahmed suggested you can use a timer and a flag to know when you have to display the message, I left you a piece of code to get you started

```
    private const int SAVE_TIME_INTERVAL = 3 * 60 * 1000;
    private bool iWasSavedInTheLastInterval = true;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Initialize the timer to your desired waiting interval
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = SAVE_TIME_INTERVAL;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If the timer counts that amount of time we haven't saved in that period of time
        iWasSavedInTheLastInterval = false;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (iWasSavedInTheLastInterval == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save any changes before closing?");
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If a manual save comes in then we restart the timer and set the flag to true
        iWasSavedInTheLastInterval = true;
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: The if statement in the close method can really be `if(!iWasSaved)`

Comment: Yeah, it's the same but in my opinion this is way more readable

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I think this will work. I'll mark it as my answer if it does. Thanks! :)

Comment: I added `using System.Timers;` in the name space, but I keep getting red lines under "Timer" for this line of code: `Timer timer = new Timer();`. I placed it as you suggested, where `InitializeComponent();` is. Also, is this more correct? `Timer timer1 = new Timer();` Since we are telling timer1 to start for the btn_Save method? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi, in the example I used the timer class on System.Windows.Forms.Timer if you add the reference to System.Timers you will need to resolve the reference between the two namespaces, I have modfied my example to explicitly use the one in windows forms. About timer1 I accidentally added two timers to my example and I forgot to initialize the iwasSavedInTheLastInterval to true   changed all this things in my answer, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but another problem has been brought to my attention. For the btn_Save method `timer.Stop();` is instructed first. If it is a first save, I receive an error at that line because there is not timer to stop yet since the timer hasn't been started. Any ideas?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue because the code in the constructor is starting the timer therefore it should always be started by the time you hit the button. Can you post what you have so far in order to see the issue?

Comment: I added the code above. I have to adjust my question a bit because it said I had too much of only code. Anyway, it's there.

Comment: Ok, change `public frmFindAndReplace()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer timer = new Timer();` to `public frmFindAndReplace()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new Timer();` the problem is that in constructor your initializing a different variable than the one used in `btnSave_Click`

Comment: Perfect! It's fixed. Thank you so much for your help and patience.

Comment: Why would anyone use a timer for this? Just store the time the save methode is called and check the difference to the current time...

Answer (score 2):

Simply remember when the last save time was:

```
private const TimeSpan saveTimeBeforeWarning = new TimeSpan(0,1,0); //1 minute 
private static DateTime _lastSave = DateTime.Now;



   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - _lastSave) > saveTimeBeforeWarning)
    {
        if(MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save any changes before closing?") == DialogResult.Yes);
        {
             Save();
        }
    }
}

private void Save()
{
    //save data
    _lastSave = DateTime.Now
}
```